# Ошибка при копировании динамического масива (c++)

Tags: c++

Я только начинаю учить c++ и пытался скопировать динамический масив, но почемуто выдаёт ошибки на выделеной строке

> "тип массива "int *[10]" является неназначаемым"
>
> "выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним
> значением"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int* arr[10];
    int* arrb[10]{};
    delete[] arr;
```

> arr = new int[sizeof(arrb) / sizeof(arrb[0])];

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arrb) / sizeof(arrb[0]); i++)
        arr[i] = arrb[i];
}
```

Можете подсказать в чём дело? Зарание спасибо!

Comment: Зачем вы делаете это - `sizeof(arrb) / sizeof(arrb[0])`?

Comment: у вас `int* arr[10]`, т.е. `arr` - это не динамический массив, а статический массив из 10 указателей на `int`. А значит вы не можете присвоить `arr` указатель на `int`, коим является `new int[sizeof(arrb) / sizeof(arrb[0])];`

Comment: Прежде чем что-то использовать в языке, это нужно сначала изучить хоть сколько-нибудь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы совершенно неправильно делаете копию динамического пассива.

Вот хорошая [статья на тему динамических массивов](https://ravesli.com/urok-86-dinamicheskie-massivy/).

Вот краткий пример того, как надо инициализировать массив и копировать его данные.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Чтоб в консоли читались русские символы
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    // Вводим длину массива
    cout << "Введите длину массива:";
    int size;
    cin >> size;

    // Выделяем память под массивы
    int* arr = new int[size];
    int* arrb = new int[size];

    // Заполняем первый массив
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите значение массива:";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    // Копируем данные из первого массива во второй
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arrb[i] = arr[i];
    }

    // Очищаем память, чтоб не было утечки памяти
    delete[] arr;
    delete[] arrb;
}
```

Comment: оператору `new[]` соответствует `delete []`, хотя в данном примере это не столь важно

Comment: @timbars спасибо, не заметил